# Efficient way to write a list to file in python

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to write a list to a file in python. My list is about 2 million items.

My first method is:

```
# first method

f = open("myfile.txt", "w")

mylist = [1,2,3, .... ,n]

for i in mylist:

    #calculate a in function of i

    f.write(str(a))

f.close()
```

My second method is:

```
# second method

list_to_write = []

mylist = [1,2,3, .... ,n]

for i in mylist:

    #calculate a in function of i

    list_to_write.append(a)

f = open("myfile2.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(a))
```

And I have an alternative way to write the file with:

```
# third method (alternative way to write the file)

with open("myfile2.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(mylist))
```

The results are practically the same in all methods with one hundred items on my list. All times are about a half minute with minor differences between them. The problem will be when escalating to the two millions of items (and even more).

Is there another way to do it in a more efficient way?

Comment: I'm sorry in the second method is necessary to change i for a in the write method.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in method 2 or method 3. Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: Have you tried using pandas?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Does my last edition about the second method solve your doubt?

Comment: not in the slightest.

Comment: You might just use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), it's much easier than doing it by hand the way you're trying and it should be fast. Try it and compare the speeds with your examples.

Comment: Storing two million items in a list might take quite a bit of memory, depending how large each item is.  I think the first method is probably best.

Comment: Good question. I wish it was adequately answered. I'm also wondering if your second method is best than the first one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to file multiple times vs Saving it in memory and writing once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321894/writing-to-file-multiple-times-vs-saving-it-in-memory-and-writing-once)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
import json
a = [1,2,3]
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is the easiest way to serialize python objects to/from storage. It is perfect for python-python communications but not so good for communicating between python and non-python systems. In that case, [json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565848/238704) is very simple and well-supported format.

Here is a simple code snippet showing `pickle` usage.

```py
# this is saved in file "scratch.py"
import pickle
import random

r = random.Random()

l = [r.getrandbits(31) for _ in range(2_000_000)]

with open('saved.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(l, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

timing and storage on my macbook pro circa 2017:

```
$ time python3 scratch.py 

real    0m0.571s
user    0m0.512s
sys     0m0.053s

$ ls -hl saved.pkl 
-rw-r--r--  1 jameskpolk  staff   9.5M Aug 20 17:49 saved.pkl
```

Answer (score -1):

you can first convert the list into pandas Series and use the `to_csv` method to write it to disk.

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [1,2,3,...,n]
pd.Series(mylist).to_csv('myfile.txt', header=False, index=False)
```